# How do I modify this letter to symbolize a cross?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gimp, inkscape, lettering

The website from where I took this picture is a religious one and it had the i (capital letter) modified to symbolize a small cross. Maybe for some it's easy to do this but for me as a starter it's quite tricky. I will not use the font from this image. I will use another font to write the text-logo I want afterwich I want to modify the i to symbolize a cross. Any suggestions on how to do this?
Thank you!

PS. I know how to work only in Illustrator, Gimp and Inkscape.

[image: this is not a T but a capital I]

Comment: Copy, rotate the "I" and scale it down? Can you tell us what you have tried and why that didn't work.

Comment: What software are you actually using? (You tagged 3)

Comment: @Cai I am using all of them but mostly Inkscape and Illustrator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With illustrator, you can do it by this way:

1. Type a word with text tool (just press the letter `t` and type)
2. Select the text and then expand it (`Type > Create Outlines` or `cmd+shift+o`)
3. Add a basic shape (press the letter `m` in order to select the rect tool)
4. Open the pathfinder (`Window > Pathfinder`)
5. Select the letter "i" of your word and then hold the `shift` button to select the shape
6. Click on the merge icon from the pathfinder window

[image]

Hope this work for you.